# Improper integral at infinity, 0 and 1

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm trying to determine whether this improper integral is convergent or divergent
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan e^{\sin x}}{\sqrt x(x^2-1)}\,dx$$
I thought that I can use the limit comparison test and compare it to $\frac1{x^2-1}$ which diverges near $x=1$ but I'm not sure how I can divide the integral since it's not defined at $x=0$, $x=1$ and improper at $\infty$.

Comment: You can split the integral up into a sum of three integrals $\int_0^a f(x)~\mathrm{d}x+\int_a^1 f(x)~\mathrm{d}x+\int_1^b f(x)~\mathrm{d}x+\int_b^\infty f(x)~\mathrm{d}x$, where $a\in(0,1)$ and $b\in(1,\infty)$. Your integral converges if and only if all of these converge, so in particular, if one of them diverges then the entire integral converges. In particular, you could now do your comparison on the integral $\int_a^1 f(x)~\mathrm{d}x$, as it's only an improper integral at the point $1$.

Comment: For $x$ near $1$ we have $$\frac{\arctan e^{\sin x}}{\sqrt x(x^2-1)} \sim C\frac{1}{x-1}$$ so the integral doesn't converge. You'll need to consider the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).

Comment: That integral will be $$\lim_{(a,b,c,d)\to (0^+,1^-,1^+,\infty)}\int_a^b f(x)\,dx+\int_c^d f(x)\,dx$$ i.e. you want to decide if there is some $L\in\Bbb R$ such that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there are some $\delta>0,\eta<1,\rho>1$ and $M>1$ such that, for all $w\in (0,\delta)$, for all $x\in (\eta,1)$, for all $y\in (1,\rho)$ and for all $z>M$, $\left\lvert\int_w^x f(t)\,dt+\int_y^z f(t)\,dt-L\right\rvert<\varepsilon$. This is equivalent to both improper integrals existing finite.